# Can IDA run in ReactOS?

Tags: windows, ida, react-os

I have a project where I will be distributing a reverse engineering environment using vagrant and I am concerned about using a Windows image as the vm base for licensing reasons.

I would like to use ReactOS to run IDA (freeware version) and am interested in compatibility. Does IDA run in a "stable" manner under ReactOS?

Comment: No one knows your needs as well as you do.  Have you tried it?  Are there particular problems you've encountered?

Comment: Why not use linux? Or windows xp? ReactOS is basiclly based on win xp

Answer (score 0):

ReactOS itself is still alpha level software, constantly developed and regularly breaks things in mysterious ways, so I wouldn't think so - although you could test a certain SVN revision with IDA yourself and see if it works satisfactorily.